# Reload Java String in C++

Tags: java, c++, utf-8

There is a Java application that writes a string with non-english content to a file in this way:

```
byte bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
writeToFile(bytes);
```

In the C++ side, how can I read content from that file and save it to a `WCHAR[]` correctly? For example I need show the string with `MessageBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the solution at least for Windows is `MultiByteToWideChar()`